# How to use SQLite transactions when having insert statements written in loop in Bash script?

Tags: bash, sqlite, loops, transactions

I've written a script for batch inserting data into a SQLite database. I've read that i can make the script faster if i enclosed my insert statements in a single transaction. This doesn't seem to work for me, i think because i make multiple calls to sqlite3 in my loop.

```
function a {
x=1
sqlite3 test.db "BEGIN TRANSACTION"
while [[ $x -le `wc -l <<< "$l"` ]]
do
a=`sed $x!d <<< $l`
b=`sed $x!d <<< $o`
echo -ne "Unos: "$x / "$(wc -l <<< $l)" \\r
sqlite3 test.db "INSERT INTO table ("l","o") VALUES ('$a','$b')"
x=$[$x+1]
done
sqlite3 test.db "COMMIT;"
}
```

How can i avoid calling sqlite3 every time in a loop? Is it possible to resume the first command outside the loop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-write your function so all of those commands get their standard output redirected to a pipe to sqlite all in one go:

```
function a {
  x=1
  (echo "BEGIN TRANSACTION;"
   while [[ $x -le `wc -l <<< "$l"` ]]
   do
    a=`sed $x!d <<< $l`
    b=`sed $x!d <<< $o`
    echo -ne "Unos: "$x / "$(wc -l <<< $l)" \\r
    echo "INSERT INTO table ("l","o") VALUES ('$a','$b');"
    x=$[$x+1]
  done
  echo "COMMIT;") | sqlite3 test.db
}
```

Putting a list of commands in parenthesis makes them all be executed in a subshell, and redirection of that list's standard input and output applies to everything in it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted! I appreciate your help